# The maximum size of array not to ruin the performance on smartphones?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, mobile

I am currently building a mobile application for smartphones

What is the maximum size of array of English words that I can include in my program, which will not effect the performance of the phone?

Is it an array of English words of 500K words?

Thanks a lot Stack Overflow!

Comment: you should be asking "how much memory can I use in my app"? Doesn't matter if you're using an array, or a linked list, or a massive blob of memory with some totally custom data structure in it. it all boils down to how many bytes your app is tying up, v.s. the total number of bytes available. And that boils down to "well, what OS/hardware are you on?"\

Comment: 0. The answer is a size-zero array to not affect performance. Any algorithm you use with this array will be at O(n) at the very least, and as such any array size greater than 0 will degrade performance.

Comment: "Oxford English Dictionary contains full entries for 171,476 words in current use, and 47,156 obsolete words." :) 500K?

Comment: @Marc: please don't give the impression that that might be a valid question here; I think I know what you *mean* by that, but if the OP *asked* that question it would *still* be off-topic (for multiple reasons).

Comment: @david: I already voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading all words into an array, you could have a file that has all the words. Load into memory only the words that are most used.

500 000 words seems a lot for a single application. I doubt you would need that.

Edit: Or better, use android's integrated SQLite, as [amphetamachine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237955/amphetamachine) said.

Comment: Or better yet, a well-maintained data access layer like SQLite.

Comment: Yeah, definitively, good point.

Comment: Thanks, that does sound like an excellent idea.  Is it a bad idea to do this?  I want to store the user's information such as the user's name, user's ID, user's level and the number of times the user ran this program.  Is it bad idea to create one table with only one row?